# Replace tf.gather with other OPs which are supported by TFLite GPU delegate

Tags: android, tensorflow, tflite, warp

Does anyone know how to replace `tf.gather` with other OPs which are supported by TFLite GPU delegate? I want to convert a TensorFlow model with a `warp` operation to a TFLite model to be used on Android devices, but the `warp` needs to use `tf.gather` to get corner pixel values and `tf.gather` seems not supported by GPU on Android.

```
def gather(y_coords, x_coords, name):
    with tf.name_scope("gather-" + name):
        linear_coordinates = batch_offsets + y_coords * width + x_coords
        gathered_values = tf.gather(flattened_grid, linear_coordinates)
        return tf.reshape(gathered_values, [batch_size, num_queries, channels])
```

Comment: Could you check with tf.gather_nd or tf.slice. For GPU delegate, Requirement is operations has to be 16 or 32 bit float operations . [Ref](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu#:~:text=GPUs%20do%20their,on%20the%20GPU.)